# What does そうべ mean?

Tags: meaning

It is in the title of a book named そうべえまっくろけのけ. How to split そうべえまっくろけのけ?

Answer (score 5):

`そうべえ` is the name of a person. `そうべ` does not mean anything.

> そうべえ　まっ　　　　　　くろ 　け　の　け
>   Soubee 　purely/really black -ish and "ke"
>   'Soubee, who turned entirely black-ish-ish'

`のけ` does not mean much, but is just making it rythmic, repeating the `け`.